# Formatting legend to include exponent in Matlab

Tags: matlab, legend

very simple question here that I can't find an answer to.. I know how to adjust the values in the axes but for the legend, I want to include the value of a certain number that's on the order of 1e6. At the moment, the legend is printing out all digits instead of the exponent. How do I force it to print the exponential format? So far, I have:

```
str1 = sprintf('Re = %2.2f', Re);
str2 = sprintf('D = %2.1f m', D);
legend(str1,str2,'Location','southeast');
```

And Re is a value being calculated higher up in the code and it is the one I want to force to print exponentially.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `e` fromat specifier instead:

```
str1 = sprintf('Re = %2.2e', Re);
```

You can also use `g` which will automatically choose between `f` and `e` based on the size of resulting string.